# Event delegation in jQuery, how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-delegation

In JavaScript i used to use event delegation like this :

```
someDiv.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    if(evt.target.id == "#someChild"){
       // Do something..
    } else if(evt.target.id == "#anotherChild"){
       // Do something else..
    }
}, false);
```

What's the equivalent of this in jQuery? i know about `.on()` but how to use it in event delegation ? i mean is this how is it done :

```
someDiv.on('click, '#someChild, #anotherChild", function(evt){
      if($(this).is("#someChild")){ 
           // Do something..
      } else if($(this).is("#anotherChild")){
           // Do something else ..
      }      
});
```

But wouldn't it be just the same as in vanilla JavaScript ? I want to know if there's a better way to achieve it. And if this is the only way, what's the benefit of jQuery way over JS one ?

Comment: Well for one, `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE below IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(someDiv).on('click', '#someChild, #anotherChild', function(){
    if(this.id ==='someChild'){ 
       // Do something..
    } else if(this.id === 'anotherChild'){
       // Do something else ..
    }      
});
```

Or create two event handlers if you do different things for both elements anyway:

```
$(someDiv).on('click', '#someChild', function(){
     // Do something..    
}).on('click', '#anotherChild', function() {
     // Do something else ..
});
```

> But wouldn't it be just the same as in vanilla JavaScript ? I want to know if there's a better way to achieve it. And if this is the only way, what's the benefit of jQuery way over JS one ?

Of course it's basically the same, jQuery just makes your life a bit easier by providing a wrapper around the DOM API, but it does not change how the DOM works.

There is a difference though, namely that `this` will refer to the element matched by the selector, not to the element the handler is bound to.

In general, the advantage is that the jQuery code is more cross-browser compatible than using `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you'd do it like this:

```
function onButtonClick(e) {
  //this = the button that was clicked

}

$(document.body).on('click','button',onButtonClick)
```

You can read the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You could start here, if this element is created dynamically, and not there on page load

```
$(document).on('click', '#someChild', function(evt) {
   // Do something..      
});
```

If the element is created before the page is rendered then this will work

```
         <input type="button" onclick="fnClickfn();" id="xxx" />
```

EDIT:

Oh, also `.on` only works in later versions on jQuery (I think 1.6 and above), so make sure you aren't using an old version that would require `.live` and `.die`.

Comment: you could replace $(document) with anything that is a parent of the div that is dynamically created, but the parent can not be dynamically created , so document usually works