# Dynamic table row with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamic building html table with rows for the users to have the option to remove or add new rows. My code is replacing both A tag onclick event and I wanted to know if there is a way to stop this from happening

```
var addrow = "<a><span class='btn btn-nccnBlue' onclick=\"AddNewRow(1, 'false')\"><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></span></a>";
        var remrow = "<a><span class='btn-red' onclick=\"RemoveRow(1, 'false')\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span></a>";
        td.innerHTML = addrow + remrow;


function AddNewRow(type) {
    debugger;
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("example");
    var trlength = $('#example tbody tr').length + 1;
    var lasttr = $('#example tbody tr:last').clone();
    lasttr.find('span').attr('onclick', 'RemoveRow(' + trlength + ')');
    lasttr.find('span').attr('onclick', 'AddNewRow(' + trlength + ')');
    $('#example tbody').append(lasttr);
}
function RemoveRow(type) {
    debugger;
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("example");
    $("#AssetRow").clone().appendTo(tableRef);
}

In my html code the class btn red should be RemoveRow(4) not AddNewRow(4)

<span class="btn btn-nccnBlue" onclick="AddNewRow(4)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>

<span class="btn-red" onclick="AddNewRow(4)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Do not use attr() to add event listeners.

Comment: I can suggest that you stop using onevent attributes -- especially if you are using jQuery.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is not an event delegation issue.

Comment: @gaetanoM And yet the answers there will resolve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in these two lines:

```
lasttr.find('span').attr('onclick', 'RemoveRow(' + trlength + ')');
lasttr.find('span').attr('onclick', 'AddNewRow(' + trlength + ')');
```

Because you have two span elements you need to distinguish between them:

```
lasttr.find('span:last').attr('onclick', 'RemoveRow(' + trlength + ')');
lasttr.find('span:first').attr('onclick', 'AddNewRow(' + trlength + ')');
```

```js
function AddNewRow(type) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("example");
    var trlength = $('#example tbody tr').length + 1;
    var lasttr = $('#example tbody tr:last').clone();
    lasttr.find('span:last').attr('onclick', 'RemoveRow(' + trlength + ')');
    lasttr.find('span:first').attr('onclick', 'AddNewRow(' + trlength + ')');
    $('#example tbody').append(lasttr);
}
function RemoveRow(type) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById("example");
    $("#AssetRow").clone().appendTo(tableRef);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">


<table id="example">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="btn btn-nccnBlue" onclick="AddNewRow(1)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
            <span class="btn-red" onclick="RemoveRow(1)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd suggest, as per comment, the correct way to add events: [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230057/event-delegation-in-jquery-how-to-do-it)).
You may take a look [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for event delegation and [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/) for event binding.

```js
//
// delegate click event on tr span inside the table
//
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr span', function(e) {
//                              ^^^^^^^^^
    if ($(this).find('>i').is('.fa-plus')) {
        var trlength = $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').length + 1;
        var newRow  = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        newRow.find('td:last').text(trlength);
        $(this).closest('tbody').append(newRow);

        return;
    }
    if ($(this).find('>i').is('.fa-times')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">


<table id="example">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="btn btn-nccnBlue"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
            <span class="btn-red"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and please have them add the events the RIGHT way

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain what you mean the RIGHT way?

Comment: By using `on()` to bind event listeners

Comment: @epascarello Done