# use MutationObserver to make jQuery recognize attribute of new button (inserted via ajax)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mutation-observers

I am trying to trigger an event when clicking on buttons that get inserted via ajax into a div. My buttons have the class `btn`.

The code below works only on buttons that were already in the DOM:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    alert('It works!');
});
```

I am using the MutationObserver example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to recognize a new child node has been made to my div and I do get a response in my console with: `A child node has been added or removed.`

How to make jQuery also recognize this child node and its attributes so i can trigger events with my inserted buttons?

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230108): attach the listener on a mutual parent and specify the selector: $('mututal parent selector').on('click, '.btn', function() { ... })

Comment: @wOxxOm This works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by wOxxOm I had to use event delegation in order to make it work.

```
$('#divID').on('click','.btn', (function(){
    alert('It works!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the `.on()` method:

```
$('.btn').on("click", (function(){
    alert('It works!');
});
```

Comment: This gives the same results unfortunately. It works on my already existing buttons but not the newly added ones.