# Button doesn't works if is created by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension (my first extension) for google Chrome.

I have a problem, if I write html code for button directly in popup.html it works but if I use javascript to create that html/button that button doesn't works. I didn't get any error from my console.

Button appears in html but if I click on it any event is launched.. Code button is the same.

Example

this code:

```
<button type="button" id="button1">Connect</button>
```

If I paste this code directly in popup.html works but if is create with

```
    for (i in dataservers.servers) {    
var serverNumberList = "button"+[i];
x +=   "<button type='button' id='"+ serverNumberList +"'>Connect</button>";

document.getElementById("viewServers").innerHTML = x;
}
```

doesn't works..

Button call:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    window.alert('GO!');
});
```

[image: First button works the second button doesn't works]

In this screenshot you can look that the code is the same. The first one works the second on doesn't works.
Some idea?

### SOLVED

in my comment I found:

When you write $("#button1") the elements must exist at that time, but they don't in your case AFAICT, so if my guess is right you need to use event delegation. – wOxxOm

I solved with this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(evt) {
    window.alert('GO!');     
 });
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: use `.on` method rather than click

Comment: `$("#button111").on( "click", function() {
  window.alert('GO!');
});` try this

Comment: When you write `$("#button1")` the elements must exist at that time, but they don't in your case AFAICT, so if my guess is right you need to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230094).

Comment: I usually go with this approach for dynamically created clickable elements

$(document).on('click', "#some_selector", function(){});

Comment: Are there really two buttons with same `id="button1"`? If so that would definitely be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dataserversServers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let x = '';
for (i in dataserversServers) {
  var serverNumberList = "button" + [i];
  x += "<button class='serverButtons' type='button' id='" + serverNumberList + "'>Connect</button>";

  document.getElementById("viewServers").innerHTML = x;
}

$(".serverButtons").on('click', function() {
  window.alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewServers"></div>
```

Try this

```
$("#button111").on( "click", function() { 
    window.alert('GO!'); 
});
```

and make sure, you are creating buttons with unique `Ids`. OR use `class` instead

Comment: Sorry for my bad example, id is unique, I set it just for the screenshot, If I remove html code with  id="button111"  I get the same problem. Btw thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: try that code in browser console and then try to click the button

Comment: I tried to use class, but this, didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works since the click on the document will value the element being clicked and match it against the selector provided in parameter 2

```
$(document).on('click', "#button111", function(){
     alert("I was pressed");
});
```

Comment: Tried, same problem.. :(

Comment: I made this jsfiddle just now, take a look at it and you should be able to figure it out. https://jsfiddle.net/4h3vxbd5/1/